# Canvas issue with fabric.IText

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm working on project for Canvas editor.I have this issue :User can add text and edit it in canvas but when delete first text and try to put again text,new text can't be edit.I use fabricjs.
For add text i use this code.

```js
$("#addText").on("click", function addText() {
  var oText = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', { 
    left: 100, 
    top: 100,
    fontSize: 26,
  });

 oText.set({ fill: $(".addText-options .sp-preview-inner").css("background-color") });
   oText.id = 'userDesign';
 
 canvas.add(oText).renderAll().setActiveObject(oText);
activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();  

});
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: The all code is too long to put it here if you want i can send you link to live site to see what is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.The problem was in version of fabricjs i used i just change version.